Adding XMLWriter instance to another one
Let's use this virtual structure to discuss the problem:
$data = [
  'lvl1' => [
    'lvl2' => [
      'lvl3' => 'data3'
    ],
    'val2' => 'data2'
  ]
];

I'm using PHP XMLWriter class to create a document in memory:
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->startElement('p');
$xml->text("Test");
$xml->endElement();
recursiveNodes($data, $xml);
$xml->endDocument();
print($xml->outputMemory());

A function should process the data array recursively:
function recursiveNodes(array $data, XMLWriter $xml) : XMLWriter
{
  foreach ($data as $node) {
    if (is_array($node)) {
      recursiveNodes($node, $xml);
    } else {
      $xml->writeElement($node);
    }
  }
  return $xml;
}

Now, in my code i'd like to use some recursive functions which adds nodes after the '<p>' node.
Due to the nature of recursive calls the last (deepest) node would be added to the XML structure first, but it should be in the same order as the data appears.

Wouldn't it be better to just pass the XMLWriter object to the recursive method so it can just carry on writing to the same document?

Maybe you are right... i rewrote my question to make the problem more clear. I just wonder how to do it recursive, because the processing order will be opposite from the order in the resulting XML.

Do you need only this output: <p>Test</p><lvl1><lvl2><lvl3>data3</lvl3></lvl2><val2>data2</val2></lvl1>? Or is there also a requirement that some additional actions should be performed inside recursiveNodes() in the specific order?

XMLWriter is writing in sequence, and recursively using its protocol requires to align it with the XML document structure.
E.g. when calling writeElement() it will write an element that is a leaf node.
And when calling startElement() ... endElement() it will write a parent node.
When you would like to use the recursive function to decorate the $data structure by traversing it recursively, your routine only has the leaf node part:
    if (is_array($node)) {
      recursiveNodes($node, $xml);
    } else {
      $xml->writeElement($node);
    }

Therefore the parent nodes are missing. It is not entirely clear to me from your question, but perhaps wrapping it for $data from the key may already suffice:
  foreach ($data as $node => $children) {
    $xml->startElement($node);
    if (is_array($children)) {
      ...
    }
    $xml->endElement();
  }

Remark: $node is now the key, and the value previous under the same variable name is now the $children variable.
